# PHP PDO: Number of Bound Variables do not Match

Tags: php, database, pdo

I have the following PHP code:

```
$insertQuery = "INSERT INTO `Some_Database`
(`time`, `timestamp`, `price_btc`, `volume_btc`, `market`, `price_usd`, `difficulty`)
VALUES (:current_time, :current_timestamp, :price_btc, :volume_btc, :doge_market, :price_usd, :difficulty)";
$insertStmt = $database->prepare($insertQuery);
$insertStmt->bindParam(":current_timestamp", $currenttimestamp);
$insertStmt->bindParam(":price_btc", $priceBTC);
$insertStmt->bindParam(":volume_btc", $volumeBTC);
$insertStmt->bindParam(":price_usd", $priceUSD);
$insertStmt->bindParam(":difficulty", $difficulty);
$insertStmt->execute(Array(":current_time" => $currentTime, ":doge_market" => $dogeMarket)); // Note: this is line 101
```

(`$database` is a PDO database object, and the other variables referenced all exist).

I get a single error:

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]:
Invalid parameter number:
number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in somepath/somefile.php on line 101
```

I'm not sure why this occurs. I checked all of the parameter references, and they're correct as far as I can tell. So, I don't know how to fix it. Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Some_Database` has really to have quotes?

Comment: @SakhalTurkaystan Technically they're backticks, but that has nothing to do with my question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) you must **EITHER**

1. Bind parameters
2. Submit parameters as an array of arguments

You are doing both, in which case you are not filling all of the provided parameters. Easy fix, use bindParam() or bindValue() calls for current_time and doge_market.